# UIGestureRecognizerDelegate never shows tap as in state 'recognized'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Im slightly confused by a method in the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate protocol. When I implement the delegate method below, I don't seem to ever get my UITapGestureRecognizers sent to this method with their state as `UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized`. They are always in the state `UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible`. Is this right?

Below is the test code I used to setup my Tap Gesture and my test implementation of the delegate method:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singelTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:nil action:nil];    
singelTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singelTap.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:singelTap];
```

.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
        int i = 0;

        if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
            i=1;
        }
        if(gestureRecognizer.state == ..... //testing for all possible states...


return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this in the documents

> This method is called before touchesBegan:withEvent: is called on the gesture recognizer for a new touch.

So I guess the touch can only ever be in the 'possible' state.

Answer (score 4):

This is correct. When you implement the

`(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch`

method, you get an opportunity to decide if the UIGestureRecognizer *should* receive the touch. That means that **it has not received the touch yet**. Because the UIGestureRecognizer in question has not received anything to do with that particular touch yet, it hasn't been able to determine if it Recognized it or not; thus it remains in the state `UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible` during this method.

If you return `YES` from the method, the touch will be sent to the UIGestureRecognizer.

Only then will the UIGestureRecognizer handle the touch.

Comment: Remember that if you return YES from the above method you are not saying the UIGestureRecognizer must Recognize the touch, you are only saying that the touch is a valid touch for that UIGestureRecognizer. After that, all of your UIGestureRecognizers will be able to determine which one if any should transition to the state UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized.

Answer (score 1):

The `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol is only to fine-tune the gesture recognizer's behavior. The actual recognition of events is done by setting a target and a selector:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
             initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)] autorelease];

// add gr to a view


-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tg
{
    if ( tg.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized ) return;
    NSLog(@"tap recognized");
}
```

In most cases, you can safely ignore the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol.

Comment: yes, I know that. But my understanding was that the gestures were sent to the delegate method on each of their state changes. Is this not the case then?

Comment: No. There is no need to call the delegate methods in any other state than `UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible`, if you're only asking to recognize a single tap. Please explain what delegate method you think should be called, and why.

Comment: I need to decide if i want to react to the TapGesture based on the UITouch i.e. if it was over a particular subview, allow the gesture, otherwise don't allow. Problem is  that with several other taps and gestures being recognised, I only want allow the gesture once it has been recognised. If i use the 'handledTap' method, i lose the information contained in UITouch.

Comment: Like what information? You can simply call `[tg locationInView:view];` to get the tap location.

Comment: UITouch provides a view method which lets you check if the clicked on view (e.g. could be one of many subViews) is of a particular class. I cant see how to do this without using the UITouch sent to the delegate.